# New FormData(SomeForm) Not Calling Custom Getter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, form-data

I have a custom dropdown componant. Within this component, I set a custom getter and setter shown below:

```
Object.defineProperty(this.DropDownInputTarget, 'value', {
    get: function() {
        return this.dataset.inputValue ?? nativeInputGetter.call(this);
    },
    set: function(value: string){
        nativeInputSetter.call(this, value);
    }
});
```

When using this in code or via the inspector console, I get the expected result. But when I am getting the form data via `new FormData(SomeForm)`, the value is always null. Is there something I need to do for this to work as expected?
Example from inspector:

```
code: document.querySelector('#Item1_ShippingInfo_StoreOptions_OtherLocationId').value
response: "BRXSL"
```

How I get my form data:

```
const formData = new FormData(shippingForm);
```

All other values from the other inputs are retrieved correctly.

As far as why I am using a custom getter, this is for a custom drop down component. The actual value of the selected item is different from the displayed value. I keep the actual value in a data attribute. This is what the custom getter retrieves.

Here is a picture of what the values look like in the console. Note that I am getting null in the FormData object, but a value when I get the input.value.
[image]
And this is what it looks like if I don't use Ajax to submit the form:
[image]

I do have a work-around, but it is less than ideal. It requires me to set the value I am missing manually after I create the `formData` object.

```
const formData = new FormData(shippingForm);
formData.set('Item1.ShippingInfo.StoreOptions.OtherLocationId', 
shippingForm.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('#Item1_ShippingInfo_StoreOptions_OtherLocationId').value);
```

Comment: If you submit the form normally, rather than with AJAX, does it use your getter?

Comment: @Barmar No, same issue still. I am pretty sure it still uses FormData underneath.

Comment: I think you need to read the specification of [form-associated custom elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#form-associated-custom-elements) to see how you can customize the value. I haven't read through it myself.

Comment: It looks like you're supposed to define a `setFormValue()` method, not customize the `value` getter.

Comment: I will look into that, I thought it just used .value (as that would make the most sense). If I find anything before an answer pops up here I will self answer the question.

Comment: @Barmar Not 100% sure yet, but reading the documentation you linked, it says that when it makes an entry list, the `value` of each item is set by the input's `value`. So in that case it SHOULD be using my custom value getter?

Comment: I don't see where you see that. Throughout that document it talks about the "submission value", and `setFormValue()` sets this. I think you may be confusing the `value` property with the `value` DOM attribute, which is used to initialize the submission value from the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `internals.setFormValue()` can work, this requires the input to be a custom input. This way you can call `HTMLElement.attachInternals()`.

After that, you need to make sure the custom element class has this variable defined at the class level: `static formAssociated = true;` so that it will be picked up when creating a new FormData.

If your input is not a custom element, this approach will not work as `HTMLElement.attachInternals()` will not work in built in types.

I chose to not go this route because:

1. Typescript does not have the best support for custom elements.
2. Making a custom element would have required a lot of changes to the existing code.

Solution:
Add a hidden input element. This is the input element I will bind to in c# as well as update the value for when I select an item.

```html
<div class="select-container">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Other Location" data-custom-validation="dropdownValidation" data-dropdown-action="search" data-dropdown-input/>
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Location" />
  <!-- Additional HTML for the select componant -->
<div>
```

In the above example, the hidden input is after the visible one. The visible input will still show what is "selected" while the hidden input gets updated to the current value I want to be submitted.
Because the visible input has no name or value, it will not be captured when creating the form data.